# .NET SignalR client crashing

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr.client, .net-4.6

I have a self-hosted Katana OWIN service with windows authentication (no https), that publishes a SignalR hub. Everything is at latest NuGet level, net4.6.2. The hub is publishing log events from NLog.

I need to access this hub from a WPF client. Just to make sure, I have a simple javascript client also, which is getting the messages as needed. But the c# client "crashes".

At an unpredictable point in time I see this in output window:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll 
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll 
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.dll 
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in mscorlib.dll
```

And from that point on the On event is not fired anymore, even if not a single message arrived before:

```
        public static async Task<bool> ConnectAsync()
        {
            var settings = new Properties.Settings();

            Connection = new HubConnection(settings.WebAPI);
            Connection.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

            HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("NLogHub");
            HubProxy.On<DTO.WebApi.List.Log>("logEvent", (logEvent) => {
                Debug.WriteLine(logEvent.TimeStamp);
                //LogEventArrived?.Invoke(logEvent);
                });
            try
            {
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 10;
                await Connection.Start(new LongPollingTransport());
                Connection.EnsureReconnecting();
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

I have tried other transports too, but no luck. Does not matter what is in the On event - can be fully empty, this still happens. 
Both client and server are running now on Windows 2016. but server will be Windows 2012, clients Windows 7 for now.

[Update 1]

The exception is thrown/not catched somewhere inside SignelR client code. Depending on transport this is what I can get:

LongPollingTransport
[image: LongPollingTransport]
WebSocketTransport
[image: WebSocketTransport]

After adding trace, I have some more details (WebSocketTransport), but still no idea how to handle:

```
13:48:04.9934736 - b3378218-e7f5-4ab4-89f6-08e6579bc70a - WS: OnMessage({})
13:48:10.1545908 - b3378218-e7f5-4ab4-89f6-08e6579bc70a - OnError(System.TimeoutException: Couldn't reconnect within the configured timeout of 00:00:30, disconnecting.)
13:48:10.1595862 - b3378218-e7f5-4ab4-89f6-08e6579bc70a - Disconnected
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in mscorlib.dll
13:48:10.1675878 - b3378218-e7f5-4ab4-89f6-08e6579bc70a - Transport.Dispose(b3378218-e7f5-4ab4-89f6-08e6579bc70a)
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
13:48:10.2616468 - b3378218-e7f5-4ab4-89f6-08e6579bc70a - Closed
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.OperationCanceledException' in mscorlib.dll
```

As I mentioned before: the JavaScript client is working like a charm.

[Update 2]

All transports complain about n ot being able to reconnect. But nothing points on a connection lost. How to debug that?

Any idea is appreciated...

Comment: Try to get the stacktrace to know where exactly (the code line) is throwing the exception.

Comment: This is what I got without source:
System.InvalidOperationException occurred
Message: Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.dll
Additional information: An asynchronous call is already in progress. It must be completed or canceled before you can call this method.
($exception).StackTrace = at System.Net.ChunkParser.SetReadParameters(Byte[] userBuffer, Int32 userBufferOffset, Int32 userBufferCount)

Comment: Open the exception details and look for Stactrace property. You just showed us the Exception and the message, but not the stacktrace. It as a large string that have information of all lines of code that throws the exception back

Comment: There are no exception details. The only details I see are in the $exception autogenerated variable. As I said: it is not in my code, I suppose it has no necessary debug information included. My code is running unaltered.
If i use default transport, I get socketexception insted, so it is certenly coming from SignalR task somewhere...

Comment: I see now that my problem is related to the timeout. But this question is not yet targeting this. So I will open a new, nore precise one.

Comment: @ZorgoZ Do you have a link for this new question?

Comment: @Carsten Nope. I have abandoned this thread and I have implemented a polling scenario.